# Why Blazor WebAssembly Core Hosted on production environment throw 'service-worker.js' error

Tags: c#, signalr, service-worker, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

my IT team launched Blazor WebAssembly Core Hosted app on production environment, app work under HTTP.

App on local environment worked perfectly. I tested from VS level using HTTPS, HTTP even as Windows Service. Everything work very good. I could always install app as PWA or send logs from Client.Side to Server.Side using SignalR.
But on production look like something is wrong with SignalR, because browser throwing exception like:

- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'register') in this line `<script>navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');</script>`
- cant comunicate with defined Hub
  WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.xxx.xx.xx/hubs/logging?id=zje1tgypHviE9Pm4EC88TA' failed:
- and option to instal app as PWA dont show :/

What is inside dev browser:

- Which code line:
  [image]
- Console:

[image]

Comment: During fast research i found information that service-worker need Secure Context, so that mean that on HTTPS or localhost app work as should.
There is some workaround of that? Or maybe I'm in mistake?